# I tried to get AVSpeechSynthesizer audio file, but it gave me an error，Thread 1: Exception: "An AVSpeechUtterance shall not be enqueued twice"

Tags: ios

I am stuck a little bit.

Here is my code:

```
speeechutterance.voice = voice;
 [_avSpeaker speakUtterance:speeechutterance];

__block AVAudioFile *output = nil;
if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
         [_avSpeaker writeUtterance:speeechutterance
                   toBufferCallback:^(AVAudioBuffer * _Nonnull buffer) {
             AVAudioPCMBuffer *pcmBuffer = (AVAudioPCMBuffer*)buffer;
             if (!pcmBuffer) {
                 NSLog(@"Error");
                 return;
             }
             if (pcmBuffer.frameLength != 0) {
                 //append buffer to file
                 if (output == nil) {
                     output = [[AVAudioFile alloc] initForWriting:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:alawFilePathName]
                                                         settings:pcmBuffer.format.settings
                                                     commonFormat:AVAudioPCMFormatInt16
                                                      interleaved:NO error:nil];
                 }
                 [output writeFromBuffer:pcmBuffer error:nil];
                 NSLog(@"pcmbuffer=%d",[output writeFromBuffer:pcmBuffer error:nil]);
             }
        }];
} else {
         // Fallback on earlier versions
}
.......
```

**how to fix this problem and how to use the function  'writeUtterance'**
*please some one can help me?*

Comment: What happens if you remove the initial call to speakUtterance: ? It seems likely that writeUtterance and speakUtterance: might both involve queueing the utterance.

Comment: if i remove the initial speakUtterance  the program won't go wrong,but still i can't get the file.and it show's me ''CreateDataFile failed
2020-09-08 10:55:28.171803+0800 Secueye[3863:1333045]  Couldn't create a new audio file object"

Comment: We're straying into the territory of a different question here.  I don't think there's quite enough code to tell why your file wouldn't be writing. I suspect something with the filepath, but you'll need to check the error that comes back in the initForWriting and make sure your file path is formatted correctly.